# Django using url to get only the url part of a named view with parameters

Tags: python, django, dry, django-urls

I want to use the {% url %} tag to get the url of a named view that takes a parameter.

I want to get the URL without the parameter and pass the parameter later using javascript. So I don't know the value of the parameter when the template renders ! If I try the url without parameters then it says "reverse not found"... I know I can hard code the url in my javcascript code but that's not DRY !!!

Thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try the following:

```
url(r'^test/(\d+)/$', 'test_view', name='test-view'),
url(r'^test/$', 'test_view', name='test-view'),
```

And return a 404 if the parameter is not provided (in case someone would actually access this uri).

Answer (score 2):

When I've had to do this in the past, I've used a sentinel value for the parameters, ie one that I know will never be passed for real, and used a regex in Javascript to replace it with the real ones.

```
{% url my_view "anobviouslyfakeparameter1" "anotherparamthatwillneverhappenforreal" %}
```

Comment: I like! I guess you'd need to parse it to modify it with JS anyways.